# AC adapter more wattage than required issues

Tags: power-supply

Many say it is safe using an AC adapter exceeding the required current.
But [this source](http://www.apogeekits.com/power_adapter_selection.htm) says:

> a power adapter that can provide more current than the load requires will sometimes work, but if the current difference is very large (say 30 to 50%) be aware that "ripple voltage" on the adapter output may be higher than ideal, and a filtering capacitor may be required to smooth out the DC output voltage of the adapter.

So, is it better to stick closely to the required current?
(obviously assuming the specs are reliable)

EDIT: in my case i'm considering [this 90W power supply](https://www.hama.com/00012120/hama-universal-notebook-power-supply-15-24-v-90-w) for a 45W load.

Comment: @Cornelius: i tried to add this as a comment but i haven't enough rep to do that. :(

Comment: In this context, it seems like you're talking about switch-mode power supplies, which can have different behavior under light loads.

Comment: You always have enough rep to edit your own posts to modify or add to the information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant to say **AC to DC adapter**.

In this case, you should know that the ripple voltage is directly proportional to the current:

\$V_r = {I \over 2fC} \$

in case of a full wave rectifier, where f is the AC frequency and C is the smoothing capacitor value.

So the more current drawn, the more ripple. Higher power supplies always have higher value smoothing capacitors, so **the bigger the better**. Adding extra smoothing capacitor over the output is a good idea.

Note that the best solution is a DC regulated adaptor (of course that depends on what do you want to supply).

Sticking closely to required current is a matter of cost and size.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be looking at the section on unregulated adapters. It's best to pick an adapter that (at least) **meets** or *somewhat* exceeds the current ratings on the original adapter.

If you use an unregulated adapter that is rated for a huge amount greater than the original, the average output voltage can be much higher than expected by the designer, and the life of the product can be compromised due to excessive heating.

Comment: I not sure if the adapter i'm considering is regulated or not, but [these benchmarks](http://uk.hardware.info/productinfo/148151/hama-universeel-notebook-netadapter-90w#tab:testresults) show the output voltage is within the [recommended 5% variation](http://uk.hardware.info/reviews/3151/4/round-up-of-74-laptop-power-adapters-original-or-universal-efficiency-and-ripple) for any load, and so can be considered safe.